# Quick login using SharedPreferences bypasses user being shown on Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase

So I am working on an android app where the user must login with their username and password and then Firebase will show users that are online after they have logged in. To save the user from all the frustration of logging in all the time, I implemented the remember me checkbox using SharedPreferences. This allows users automatic or fast login once they open the app without typing the username and password all over again, saving their time and frustration.

The automatic login using remember me checkbox with SharedPreferences is working fine but when the user logs in without the login screen, that is, when the remember me function kicks in, data is not sent to Firebase and users are not seen as available or online when they are actually on the app.

The first solution would be to implement a method whereby when the user logs in automatically(due to remember me), then the app communicates with Firebase and shows the user is online. This is more preferable so if anyone can please help me out with this.

The other is to save/show the previously typed username and password in the respective EditText fields so the user just has to press the login button. By this method, I believe that least coding would be required compared to the first solution. Once the user logs in from the login screen, information will be communicated to Firebase and will show the user as available/online.

Have searched a lot on how to implement the second solution, that is, to show the previously typed username and password but to no success. Searched keywords "show previously typed username edittext android studio" but got no relevant google and Youtube results.

Please help me out guys.

Comment: Follow this link - https://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 0):

Finally....got the solution and I am happy with the autofill or second solution. EditText fields shows the previously entered username and password so user just has to click login. Credentials are saved only if remember me checkbox is checked.

Here is the simple code that brought my breathe back:

```
 sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(myPreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPreferences.contains(Username)) {
        DriverEmail.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(Username, ""));
    }
    if (sharedPreferences.contains(Password)) {
        DriverPassword.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(Password, ""));
    }
```